# Unable to run rake db:create segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently installed `ruby -v 2.20`, and then installed `rails 4.2.6` on El Capitan.
I already had mysql installed, (`mysql-5.7.9`).

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.13', '< 0.5'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

The error which I get on rake db:create:

```
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000418
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]

-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   for more details.


-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0027 p:-17543762484298 s:0098 e:000097 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0026 p:---- s:0096 e:000095 CFUNC  :require
c:0025 p:0261 s:0092 e:000091 TOP    /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/lib/mysql2.rb:31 [FINISH]
c:0024 p:---- s:0089 e:000088 CFUNC  :require
c:0023 p:0039 s:0085 e:000084 BLOCK  /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86 [FINISH]
c:0022 p:---- s:0081 e:000080 CFUNC  :each
c:0021 p:0053 s:0078 e:000077 BLOCK  /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81 [FINISH]
c:0020 p:---- s:0072 e:000071 CFUNC  :each
c:0019 p:0032 s:0069 e:000068 METHOD /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70
c:0018 p:0017 s:0065 e:000064 METHOD /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102
c:0017 p:0049 s:0061 e:000060 TOP    /Users/sahil/Documents/work/practice/mashup/config/application.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0016 p:---- s:0059 e:000058 CFUNC  :require
c:0015 p:0113 s:0055 e:000054 METHOD /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
c:0014 p:0018 s:0045 e:000044 TOP    /Users/sahil/Documents/work/practice/mashup/Rakefile:4 [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0043 e:000042 CFUNC  :load
c:0012 p:0009 s:0039 e:000038 METHOD /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28
c:0011 p:0176 s:0035 e:000034 METHOD /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689
c:0010 p:0007 s:0030 e:000029 BLOCK  /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94
c:0009 p:0006 s:0028 e:000027 METHOD /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176
c:0008 p:0007 s:0024 e:000023 METHOD /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93
c:0007 p:0013 s:0021 e:000020 BLOCK  /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77
c:0006 p:0006 s:0019 e:000018 METHOD /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176
c:0005 p:0007 s:0015 e:000014 METHOD /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75
c:0004 p:0040 s:0012 e:000011 TOP    /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0010 e:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0119 s:0006 E:000ce0 EVAL   /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000ac0 TOP    [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/sahil/Documents/work/practice/mashup/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/sahil/Documents/work/practice/mashup/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 rax: 0x0000000000000030 rbx: 0x000000010d60da4f rcx: 0x0000000000000000
 rdx: 0xfffffffffffffff0 rdi: 0x0000000000000030 rsi: 0x0000000000000000
 rbp: 0x00007fff53506b70 rsp: 0x00007fff53506b70  r8: 0x000000000000000b
  r9: 0x00000000ffffe000 r10: 0x00007fff9a50e600 r11: 0x00007fff8c6b7c20
 r12: 0x00007fff7368d070 r13: 0x00007fa5ca406a50 r14: 0x0000000000000006
 r15: 0x00007fff53506c30 rip: 0x000000010d658aff rfl: 0x0000000000010246

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   ruby                                0x000000010c9adb3b rb_vm_bugreport + 155
1   ruby                                0x000000010c852bd0 rb_bug_context + 480
2   ruby                                0x000000010c92a693 sigsegv + 83
3   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff8c6b452a _sigtramp + 26
4   libruby.2.0.0.dylib                 0x000000010d658aff ruby_xmalloc + 17
5   ???                                 0x00007fff53506b90 0x0 + 140734591167376

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 rational.so
    2 complex.so
    3 encdb.so
    4 trans/transdb.so
    5 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/unicode_normalize.rb
    6 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/rbconfig.rb
    7 thread.rb
    8 thread.so
    9 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
   10 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
   11 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
   12 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/errors.rb
   13 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb
   14 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   15 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   16 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   17 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   18 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
   19 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   20 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   21 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   22 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb
   23 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   24 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb
   25 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   26 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   27 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/version.rb
   28 etc.so
   29 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb
   30 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/singleton.rb
   31 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/optparse.rb
   32 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/ostruct.rb
   33 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/ext/core.rb
   34 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/ext/string.rb
   35 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/ext/fixnum.rb
   36 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/win32.rb
   37 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/linked_list.rb
   38 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/cpu_counter.rb
   39 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/scope.rb
   40 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task_argument_error.rb
   41 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rule_recursion_overflow_error.rb
   42 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/shellwords.rb
   43 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb
   44 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/cloneable.rb
   45 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb
   46 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb
   47 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb
   48 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/set.rb
   49 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/promise.rb
   50 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/thread_pool.rb
   51 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/private_reader.rb
   52 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/thread_history_display.rb
   53 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/trace_output.rb
   54 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb
   55 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb
   56 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/pseudo_status.rb
   57 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb
   58 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb
   59 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/invocation_exception_mixin.rb
   60 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb
   61 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb
   62 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/file_task.rb
   63 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/file_creation_task.rb
   64 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/multi_task.rb
   65 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb
   66 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/default_loader.rb
   67 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/late_time.rb
   68 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/name_space.rb
   69 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/backtrace.rb
   70 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake.rb
   71 pathname.so
   72 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/pathname.rb
   73 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/constants.rb
   74 io/console.so
   75 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
   76 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
   77 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/build_error.rb
   78 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb
   79 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/configure_builder.rb
   80 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/delegate.rb
   81 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tmpdir.rb
   82 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tempfile.rb
   83 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb
   84 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/rake_builder.rb
   85 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/command.rb
   86 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext/cmake_builder.rb
   87 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/ext.rb
   88 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
   89 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
   90 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
   91 /Users/sahil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/environment_preserver.rb
   92 socket.so
   93 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb
   94 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb
   95 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb
   96 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc2396_parser.rb
   97 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb
   98 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb
   99 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb
  100 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/ftp.rb
  101 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/http.rb
  102 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/https.rb
  103 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/ldap.rb
  104 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/ldaps.rb
  105 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/mailto.rb
  106 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri.rb
  107 zlib.so
  108 stringio.so
  109 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/exceptions.rb
  110 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/header.rb
  111 enc/windows_31j.so
  112 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/generic_request.rb
  113 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/request.rb
  114 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/requests.rb
  115 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb
  116 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/responses.rb
  117 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/proxy_delta.rb
  118 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/backward.rb
  119 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb
  120 date_core.so
  121 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/date.rb
  122 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/time.rb
  123 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/request/http_pool.rb
  124 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/request/https_pool.rb
  125 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/request/connection_pools.rb
  126 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/request.rb
  127 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/cgi/core.rb
  128 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/cgi/util.rb
  129 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/cgi/cookie.rb
  130 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/cgi.rb
  131 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/uri_formatter.rb
  132 digest.so
  133 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/digest.rb
  134 openssl.so
  135 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/bn.rb
  136 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/cipher.rb
  137 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/config.rb
  138 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/digest.rb
  139 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/x509.rb
  140 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/buffering.rb
  141 fcntl.so
  142 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl/ssl.rb
  143 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/openssl.rb
  144 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/securerandom.rb
  145 /Users/sahil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/resolv.rb
```

Comment: Did you configure your settings to use mysql in your `config/database.yml` file?

Comment: Yes I already did, my previous projects were running, using ruby 1.9.3, then when I went on to create a new project, it said that cannot install a particular gem, as it needed ruby >= 2.0, so I installed ruby 2.2.0, and then rails again, and now I am unable to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

1) Downloaded this zip file https://structure-svm-map.googlecode.com/files/svm-map-win.zip and extracted it to a c:\tmp\svm-map

2) Downloaded Mysql C/Connector 6.1 from http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-winx64.zip and extracted it to c:\tmp\mysql

```
3) Open CMD Prompt

4) cd \tmp\svm-map\python-mingw-lib

5) gendef.exe \tmp\mysql\lib\libmysql.dll

6) move libmysql.def \tmp\mysql\lib

7) cd \tmp\mysql\lib

8) \Ruby200-x64\DevKit\mingw\bin\dlltool -v --dllname libmysql.dll --def libmysql.def --output-lib libmysql.lib

9) gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=c:\tmp\mysql
```

Please let me know it should install

Comment: Can you please tell the solution for a mac, this solution seems it would work for a windows machine?

Comment: what is the version of your mysql Please use latest version them `rvm reset` and bundle install may solve your problem

Comment: I tried bundle exec rake db:create, and it worked. But rake db:create alone does not work.

Comment: gem list rake will show all of ur system rake gems now bundle exec bind the rake gem of your application use by doing bundle install..................question is it is gem issue and rvm reset will do that

Comment: I did rvm some dotfile command as it was showing a warning message, and now it is again showing that I do not have ruby 2.2 and only have 1.9 installed. So I am back to square one.